# Selectively disable mplcursors on matplotlib plots

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, mplcursors

I'm currently using mplcursors to show a label when hovering over a line on a plot, but I have a unintended consequence of it showing a unwanted label on another plot within my application.

Is there any way to enable mplcursors on 1 plot but not another?

This is what I'm using to turn on the feature `mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mplcursors.html#mplcursors.cursor) says you can give `artists` or `axes` as inputs to `mplcursors.cursor` using the `artists_or_axes` kwarg.

So, in your case, you should give `mplcursors.cursor` just the `Axes` instance that you would like to see cursors on, and not the other one.

For example, something like this should work to only show cursors on `ax1`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)

ax1.plot(range(5))
ax2.plot(range(5))

mplcursors.cursor(artists_or_axes=ax1, hover=True)

plt.show()
```